# Emit a different tag in your Blazor component based on the consumer selection

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

Blazor on .NET 5.

I am building a Tab component that is made of a Tab, TabHeader and TabBody.
These are themes independent and the TabHeader might emit any tag such as `<li>` or `<div>` or whatever, depending on what the consumer of the component wants:

```
@page "/"
<ul>
    <TabHeader>
        <a href="#">Music</a>
    </TabHeader>
</ul>
```

In the component implementation, I will be attaching an `@onclick` and `@attributes`:

```
<li @onclick="TabSelected" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">
    @ChildContent
</li>

@code {
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
        public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

        private void TabSelected(MouseEventArgs obj)
        {
            // do something
        }
}
```

In the previous example, I have used a harcoded `<li>`, while I want to give the choice to the component consumer to determine what they want as a HTML element (maybe they want a span, li, div or whatever) and I want to attach to it `@onclick` and `@attributes`. **Is there an elegant way in Blazor to switch the tag to whatever the consumer selects?**

Maybe, as an example, by allowing the consumer to write something like:

```
...
<TabHeader Tag='li'>
   ...
</TabHeader>
...
```

Comment: Why do you want that? For one, the consumer cares about the tab, not how it's implemented. For another, you can implement *all* of the options with the appropriate styles on a list item, a div or span - you can create a list of things using `<div>` and many bootstrap "lists" are divs with styling

Comment: Besides you *can't* allow the user to supply invalid tags, eg a `<table>` or `<tr>`. You'd have to implement checks to restrict the allowed tags anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the requirements are simple, the user has to supply the tag to fit their theming framework (Bootstrap, Bulma and others) and should have total control. If they supply the wrong tag then this is their problem.

Comment: The requirement is anything but simple, and all those frameworks work with multiple tags anyway. `div` works everywhere. In that case you should see what Blazorise does. Hint: it doesn't have a `Tag` property. It provides different adapters for each framework. Checking out what the competition does is a very good strategy anyway

Answer (score 2):

I try to answer your question instead of debating about the use case. What you can do, is to not create a .razor file for your component but a purely C# file and override the `BuildRenderTree` method. This not as convenient as using a .razor file and let the compiler do its magic, but it gives you the possibility to insert any HTML tag, based on a tag parameter.

```
public class TabHeader : ComponentBase
{
  [Parameter]
        public String Tag { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, Tag);
            builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this, TabSelected));
            builder.AddContent(3, ChildContent);
            builder.CloseElement();
        }

        private void TabSelected(MouseEventArgs obj)
        {
            // do something
        }
}
```